# using program installed in WSL in windows

Tags: neovim

I have installed neovim using wsl Ubuntu-20.04. Is there a way to directly run neovim in windows, without installing it on windows.

Comment: Would starting it from Windows but having it run within `wsl` do? In that case you should be able to run `wsl nvim [<filepath>]` (I don't have a Windows machine to test it on)

Comment: @frippe Thanks it worked without even giving the filepath. Although init file dosen't get sourced probably I have to  make a different init file in users  for windows.

Comment: Great! Yeah, the filepath is optional, you only need to provide it if you want to launch nvim with a buffer for the specified file(s). Which init file are you expecting to get sourced? nvim doesn't use `~/.vimrc` by default, but defaults to `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` (or the lua counterpart), where `~/` is the _wsl_ user's home dir. Since nvim is running inside wsl, it won't pick up any windows config files (unless you explcitly point it to one, of course).

Comment: To convert windows paths to wsl and vice versa you'll have to use [wslpath](https://github.com/laurent22/wslpath)